# Should a not well received answer be deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes, deletion, deleted-answers

A answer that is not *that* well received or the one that got tonnes of downvotes, should it be deleted by the answerer ? As such answers don't add any value to the question for the future visitors! Recently I wrote an answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1755277/309526 , turns out that my high-school level knowledge wasn't complete related to the subject and now I feel that I should delete it , because as per the comments it is just a misguiding answer , but at the same time as answers are community property I'd like to discuss whether such answers be deleted or not?

Comment: you are welcome to delete an answer if people seem not to like it. Over time, you will get to know what makes for an answer that gets few downvotes or none.

Comment: @WillJagy I didn't get this part `Over time, you will get to know what makes for an answer that gets few downvotes or none.` blame it to my poor english comprehension skills

Comment: You are new here. Things will get better over time. People downvote for many reasons, not always predictable, and not always mathematical, not always fair.

Comment: Given the fact that your answer is completely wrong from a technical point of view (and I don't think that this is in dispute), I would say yes, delete it. If it was just a minor technical error but the rest of the answer is salvageable, then edit; in this case, I don't feel that applies.